# Jersey Entity Data Filtering on Glassfish 4 Service

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jersey, cdi

I would like to use the [Jersey Entity Data Filtering](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html) with Glassfish 4.0 but when i try to deploy my web application i always get a CDI error message:

> org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment
>   failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type
>   [EntityGraphProvider] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point
>   [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.EntityInspectorImpl.graphProvider]

I also tried Galssfish 4.0.1-b03

Has someone sucessfully used the Jersey Entity Data Filtering with a JAX-RS REST Service?

Answer (score 3):

Entity Filtering (and [Entity Filtering via Security Annotations](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/04/filtering-jax-rs-entities-with-standard-security-annotations/)) has been introduced in Jersey 2.3 (few months after GF 4.0) so it's little bit harder to use this feature in GF 4.0. You can use it, however, in nightly/promoted builds (i.e. GF 4.0.1-b03 as you mentioned) but you need to make sure that your WAR doesn't contain any Jersey bits (or it's dependencies like guava) as these are already present in GF.

You can take a look at [example modules for GF](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jersey-examples/2.5.1/jersey-examples-2.5.1-gf.zip) to see which modules are excluded.

Note: You can list all your JARs in your WAR and I'll tell you which ones should be removed.

Comment: When i ensure that no jersey jar file is added to WEB-INF/lib i get the following ClassNotFoundException:

2014-02-09T15:19:41.028+0100|Schwerwiegend: WebModule[/test]StandardWrapper.Throwable
MultiException stack 1 of 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/message/filtering/EntityFilteringFeature

I'm using glassfish-4.0.1-b03-ml